# VS2012 web server - change virtual path from /mysite to root

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

When I launch my website in vs2012, it opens to localhost:4661/MySite. This resolves to C:\Projects\Websites\MySite. How can I change localhost:4661 to resolve to my website at C:\Projects\Websites\MySite?

I'm using the visual studio web server.

It seems like I need to change the virtual path from /MySite to /.  But how do I do that?

I'm using a 'website' as opposed to web application project, if it helps.

This worked in vs2010, but I was using a different web server then.

I'm new to vs2012.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just remove "MySite" in the VirtualPath field under Project properties / Web / Servers.

Comment: So I right click on my project, choose property pages, but I don't see anything that references web servers or virtual path. Am I missing something? :(

Comment: Choose the "Web" tab on the left.

Comment: the tabs are References, Build, Accessibility, Start Options, MSBuild Options, and Silverlight Applications...

Answer (score 0):

Found this answer from [Imar at Programmer-to-Programmer](http://p2p.wrox.com/book-beginning-asp-net-4-5-c-vb/89330-unable-find-virtual-path-property-vs2012.html), trying to research the issue myself.

Comment: In VS2012 there are only 2 options in the project properties: Full Path and Opened URL, and both are read only. Is my web project of a wrong type?